# Accessing public datasets on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an old link to a public dataset: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-samples:reddit.full. However, it now points to a deprecation of old UI page with a link to Google Cloud console. How can I access this dataset through URL or find it in the new UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on that link to console and than change value of the project attribute in querystring to be a `bigquery-samples`. open this "new" link and bigquery-samples project will now appear in the explorer (or just use this link `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=bigquery-samples`).

Now, pin the project so next time it will be also available for you

[image]